# Entity framework 4 model first using money value object

Tags: entity-framework, currency, value-objects

I want to use a Money value object in my application. I have found several examples of a [Money datatype](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/MoneyTypeForCLR.aspx). But I can't figure out how to use them with EF4. I would like to store each amount as a Decimal/CurrencyCode pair (where currencycode is a string - "USD", "SEK", etc) in the database. I tried creating a complexType but I couldn't get that to work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It should be definitely possible. Your complex type is just pair of decimal and string property. It is exactly what complex type are used for. Depending on your approach you must do:

Database first:

You will define your database first. Your table will contain money and varchar columns representing your new type. When you update your EDMX model from database it will include it as scalar properties to your entity. You must remove those properties. Then go to model browser and create new complex type. Return back to entity and add complex property of your new complex type. And at the end you must go to entity mapping and map your complex type to those database columns.

Here is basic tutorial from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx) but from unknown reason they didn't include such elementary details like screenshots. [Here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/wriju/Complex-Type-ADONET-Entity-Framework) is some video from channel9.

Model first:

This is similar to database first but you don't have to deal with database creation and mapping. It will be generated for you.

Code first (EF 4.1):

You must create separate class for your complex type and use it as property in your entity. You should not need to map it by default - mapping should be infered. If it doesn't work you can map complext type either by using `ComplextTypeAttribute` annotation or by defining mapping in `DbModelBuilder`.

I can further extend approach you need to use if you provide more details.